# Convertir Labels a Inputs conservando Valor

Tags: javascript

me gustaría saber como, dentro de una tabla puedo cambiar los labels de un tr en concreto (con varios td, cada uno con su label) , sin eliminar la tabla y conservando el valor de los labels.

-He estado probando con innerHTML, pero me remplaza la tabla...

```js
<script>
function change(){
var valor = document.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
document.querySelector("td").innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + valor + '"/>';
      
        

</script>
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td><label>Label Ejemplo</label></td>
  <td><button type="button" onclick="change();">Cambiar a input</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label>Label Ejemplo1</label></td>
  <td><button type="button" onclick="change();">Cambiar a input</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><label>Label Ejemplo2</label></td>
  <td><button type="button" onclick="change();">Cambiar a input</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes guardar el valor del label en una variable al hacer click en el botón y cambiar todo el contenido del td por un input con esa variable.

```
   <table>
      <tr>
      <td><label>Label Ejemplo</label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
     <button type="button" onclick="change();">Cambiar a input</button>
```

A tu table le falta la etiqueta cerrar, tenlo en cuenta o te dará errores.

Como no sé si tienes o no más código o cómo es este, he cogido los tags con `querySelector` pero puedes usar `id` o `class` para que no tener problemas:

```
function change() {
var valor = document.querySelector("label").innerHTML;

document.querySelector("td").innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + valor + '"/>';
}
```

Comment: Hola Rabegi. Gracias por aportar. Pero es mejor esperar a que el autor mejore la pregunta para que sea de calidad. Si se le resuelve, no mejorará la pregunta y seguirá haciendo este tipo de publicaciones porque *"ya habrá alguien que me responda"*. Te sugiero borrarla y esperar a que la edite. Y despues, pulsar en recuperar.  Un saludo